# Straightening of a marked simplicial set

Tags: ct.category-theory, infinity-categories

Let $X$ be in $Set_{\Delta}$, let $\phi=id:\mathbb{C}X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}X$ be the map of simplicial categories over which we want to straighten. Assuming that $X$ is a quasi-category, how can one prove that all the edges of the marked simplical sets $St_{\phi}^+X^{\sharp}(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb{C}X_0$ are marked?

By induction and general techniques, I am pretty sure that this reduces to proving the result for the case $X=\Delta^2$. However, my attempts have been unsuccessful: I am missing one edge…

To be more specific, I can't figure out why the diagonal edge of $St_{\phi}^+(\Delta^2)^{\sharp}(2)\cong (\Delta^1)^2$ is marked.

NB: Definitions and notations are from HTT 3.2.

Comment: What makes you think that all the edges of $St^+_{\phi}X^{\sharp}(x)$ should be marked? I don't think that's true. For example, it indeed seems to be false for $X=\Delta^2$.

Comment: This is used in HTT 3.2.1.11.

Comment: My (wild?) guess is that the definition of HTT is not quite correct, in the sense that you should allow more edges to be marked by not limiting yourself to simplices of dimension $\leq 2$ in the definition.

Comment: Where exactly is it used in HTT 3.2.1.11?

Comment: In part (3) it is used for $\Delta^2$ and in part (4) for Kan complexes, whence the formulation of my question for a general quasi-category.

Comment: Unless there is something I'm missing, it seems that there is a mistake there. I don't think it's the definition of straightening that should be adjusted (it is constraint by having to be colimit preserving, and so the marking on the straightening must be freely induced from the marking on $X$), but simply the argument in HTT 3.2.1.11 needs to be adapted. Basically, one should show that adding all these additional edges to $St X^{\sharp}$ yields a trivial cofibration.

Comment: I agree with Yonatan. Although it may not be true  that all the edges of $\operatorname{St}(X^\sharp)(x)$ are marked, this is not a serious error. Indeed, the rest of the proof of 3.2.1.11 does not use this claim at all.